# Having a problem with simplifying a sum given that $(k+1)^3-(k-1)^3=6 k^2+2$

Tags: measure-theory, proof-explanation

I was able to prove this first part (given in the title) however I am having trouble continuing with the second part of the question:

[image: Shown here]

Any help or suggestions for how to solve this would be greatly appreciated. 
 :)

Comment: Welcome to Math Stack Exchange.  Are you familiar with [Telescoping Series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series)?

Comment: **Hint:**

$$\sum_{k=1}^nk^2=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left[\frac{(k+1)^3-(k-1)^3-2}{6}\right]$$

Comment: or $\sum_{k=1}^n \left(6k^2+2\right)=\sum_{k=1}^n \left((k+1)^3-(k-1)^3\right)=(n+1)^3+n^3-1^3-0^3$

Comment: I think the tag of measure theory could be removed.

Answer (score 0):

We can use the telescopic sum.
$$\sum_{k=1}^n(6k^2+2)=\sum_{k=1}^n((k+1)^3-(k-1)^3)=$$
$$=\sum_{k=1}^n((k+1)^3-k^3+(k^3-(k-1)^3))=(n+1)^3-1+(n^3-0).$$
Can you end it now?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Note that $$\sum_1^n 6k^2+2{=\sum_{k=1}^{n}(k+1)^3-(k-1)^3\\=\sum_{k=1}^{n}(k+1)^3-k^3+k^3-(k-1)^3\\=\sum_{k=1}^{n}(k+1)^3-k^3\\+\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^3-(k-1)^3}$$Now use the telescopic rule.